# How can you programmatically add contractions to a sentence?

Tags: nlp

I've seen many posts about expanding contractions to tokenize them correctly but I'd like to be able to add a contraction while retaining semantic accuracy. Are there any libraries addressing this or solutions available to this problem?

Positive Examples:

- "You are going to the restaurant." becomes "You're going to the
  restaurant."
- "I am a happy boy." becomes "I'm a happy boy."

Negative Examples:

- "Is that all you have?" should not become "Is that all you've?"
- "Is that who you are?" should not become "Is that who you're?"
- "You have a big heart." should not become "You've a big heart."

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer to the main question, but from the examples it seems that "have" and "be" only contract when they're used as an auxiliary. That is, they proceed another verb. Maybe something in POS tagging them, then checking if they're followed by a verb?

Edit: Nope, your second positive example disagrees with this.